# Bypass/remove reference to failed drive

Tags: linux-mint, boot, hard-disk

I have 2 hard drives in my laptop - linux mint 18.1 Serena is installed on 1 the other was unused but now appears to have failed so booting now takes over a minute.

```
dmesg:

[    4.071392] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xb051d000 port 0xb051d180 irq 42
[    9.430756] ata2: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   14.078859] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[   19.446984] ata2: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   24.095092] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[   29.463215] ata2: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   59.143901] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[   59.143914] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
[   64.176017] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[   64.176030] ata2: reset failed, giving up
```

How can I stop it trying to connect to the failed drive? Is this only possible by physically disconnecting it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try issuing `hdparm -Y /dev/<defective-one>`, but kernel may reset it automatically to start. Can you disable the SATA port from BIOS?

Comment: It is not recognised so I can't do anything at all from hdparm. In the BIOS the HDD info is incomplete - it recognises that there should be two drives but no information is displayed for the second

Answer (score 0):

It was a physically connection issue. Opened up laptop and checked hard drive connections - 2nd drive now recognised fine so no issue

Answer (score -1):

Either remove the entry for this drive from your /etc/fstab, or disable the drive in your BIOS

First, back up /etc/fstab:

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
```

Next, edit the fstab:

```
gksu gedit /etc/fstab
```

Remove the line in this file that references the drive you want to disable

Comment: This doesn't work because the drive is not connecting in the first place so is never listed.